# How to patch to version 1.7

Tags: pc, fallout-3

I just installed Fallout 3 on my computer. My OS is Windows 7 Home edition.
The Fallout 3 installation is on another SSD (not the one with Windows on it)

I download the 1.7 Patch from the official Fallout 3 homepage.

When I try to patch and update the game to 1.7, I get an error massage in the end saying something about this file xlive.dll.

**How can I safely and easily update to version 1.7?**

Comment: Non-Steam version?

Comment: @ColeBusby Non-Steam version yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [information on the Nexus support forums](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/114148-xlivedll-error/), this can be fixed by installing either

- A fresh update of [Games for Windows Live](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/live/pc/update), or
- [The Windows Live Disabler mod](http://www.fallout3nexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1086) for FO3, which will install a dummy xlive.dll

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Go onto the Fallout Nexus and download the Fallout mod manager. When that is downloaded and running, open the tools toolbar, then click on install tweaker and then check the box that says use fake xlive.dll.